# Can I change the font size of specific words of excel cell in Office.js?

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

I have a requirement to change the font size of specific words (not the complete cell) of excel cell in Office.js.
Is there any provision for this in Office.js?

Answer (score 1):

not yet. we are working on providing something similar to the characters collection, but still in early design stages.